# How to specify partition numbers when write a dataframe to parquet using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to write a spark dataframe to parquet but rather than specify it as `partitionBy`but the `numPartitions` or the size of each partition. Is there an easy way to do that in PySpark?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you care is the number of partitions the method is exactly the same as for any other output format - you can repartition `DataFrame` with given number of partitions and use `DataFrameWriter` afterwards:

```
df.repartition(n).write.parquet(some_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems `repartition` is very costly. I tried the `coalesce` but the job actually failed. Is there any requirement for `numPartition` in `coalesce` ? Should `coalesce` be less expensive than `repartition`?

Comment: Only if change is relatively small. Otherwise it has to move data so the only advantage is lack of full shuffle. From the other hand it is less likely to provide uniform distribution.